# How to make animation play on key press w, a, s, and/or d and stop when none of those are being pressed?

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine

I made a humanoid model and a walk animation for him using maya (exported as fbx). I can make the animation play indefinitely, but I want it to only play when w, a, s, or d are pressed down. Then I want it to stop when the key(s) are released.

I have my animation script attached to my player object. I also have an animation component that contains my "Player_Walk" animation, which is attached to my player object. Is there some other component I need to get for it to work correctly? or initialize something in the script? or?

Here is my script:
[image]

Thanks for the help in advance! If more info is needed, let me know.

P.S. There are other questions like this, but a lot of them and their answers were before Unity 5 was released, hence they are not very helpful.

Comment: Please tell us what is happening with the current code in your question. Also, when you say "stop when the key(s) are released"...All keys must be released or some of them before stopping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cache your `Animation` component since you called in `Update()` to improve performance.

```
Animation anim;

void Awake()
{
    anim = GetComponent<Animation>();
}

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D))
        anim.Play();
    else
        anim.Stop();
}
```

Comment: Before I saw your comment, I wrote some code very similar to this, but it didn't work still. Tried yours and doesn't work. Received error that said something like "could not find animation with name 'Player_Walk'."

But I have the animation component and script attached to the Player object and it is indeed named correctly.

Comment: so it is related to the animation, maybe you could provide image of your inspector.

Comment: Picture 1 - My inspector: http://puu.sh/sKnSC/4aeda82e23.png

Picture 2 - (part of) My Hierarchy: http://puu.sh/sKnV6/2e41c5cc59.png

Picture one is showing the inspector for "FireGuyModelAndAnim". I've tried putting both script and animation under the entire object "Player", but it has the same effect.

Comment: so are you using `Animation` or  `Animation controller` ? screenshot your `Animation controller` if you use it instead of animation

Comment: check this link, https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/animation/animator-controller , it might help you

Comment: That was helpful. I tried using an animator controller earlier, but to no luck. How do I reference the animator controller in a script? I have: "ENTRY --> IDLE <--> PLAYER_WALK" in my animator controller. My idle part is empty so it should do nothing in that state. I want to say: if w, a, s, or d is pressed then go to PLAYER_WALK state, else go to IDLE state. picture: http://puu.sh/sKpGy/99b8ddbd2a.png

Comment: Tried this script: http://puu.sh/sKpUf/76bb5209bb.png BUT all it does is make my characters arm twitch every 2 seconds and then immediately goes back to the IDLE state

Comment: use the `Animation controller` parameter, set up the trigger. and called it from script. https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AnimationParameters.html ,and set the condition, ex: IDLE > PLAYER_WALK after `walknow` (trigger) is called form script. something like that.

Comment: this tutorial explain what i said above. https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/2d-roguelike-tutorial/player-animator-controller

Comment: Ah! Got it working! Thanks a lot man. Sorry for being dumb :)

Comment: @MoreFoam Don't forget to accept his answer if it solved your problem.